# mysql select query using calculated column values

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
orderno       insurance
ABC123        3.00
ABC123        3.00
ABC123        3.00
DEF456        2.00
DEF456        2.00
```

I want to get the sum of the average insurance values for each unique order.

e.g. `(3.00+3.00+3.00)/3  +  (2.00+2.00)/2`

```
= 5
```

How can I achieve this using a MySQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT SUM(avgIns) AS oAverage
FROM
    (SELECT OrderNo, AVG(Insurance) AS avgIns
    FROM yourTableName
    GROUP BY OrderNo) iTable
```

**UPDATE**

if you want to limit your decimal places, use **FORMAT(value, decimalPlaces)**

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(avgIns),2) AS oAverage         -- Returns two decimal places
FROM
    (SELECT OrderNo, AVG(Insurance) AS avgIns
    FROM yourTableName
    GROUP BY OrderNo) iTable
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I understand apart from iTable, what should that be?

Comment: @chris `iTable` is just a name for the subquery.

Comment: Derived tables and aliases ... got it!

Comment: It won't let me upvote you until I get a reputation level of 15. When I reach this lofty goal I will return and +1 you. Thanks John

Comment: @chris if you don't add an `ALIAS`, the server will return and error: `Error Code: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: Done, much appreciated, you are very wise

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(value) from (
    select sum(insurance) / count(insurance) as value
    from yourTableName
    group by insurance
) temp;
```

Example run in mysql:

```
mysql> create table testTable (id int primary key auto_increment, orderno varchar(12), insurance decimal(6, 2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.27 sec)


mysql> insert into testTable (orderno, insurance) values ('ABC123', 3), ('ABC123', 3), ('ABC123', 3), ('DEF456', 2), ('DEF456', 2);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec) Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


mysql> select * from testTable;
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | orderno | insurance |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 | ABC123  |      3.00 |
|  2 | ABC123  |      3.00 |
|  3 | ABC123  |      3.00 |
|  4 | DEF456  |      2.00 |
|  5 | DEF456  |      2.00 |
+----+---------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select sum(value) from (     
select sum(insurance) / count(insurance) as value
from testTable
group by insurance ) temp;
+------------+
| sum(value) |
+------------+
|   5.000000 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. You can't group by the same column you are using the aggregate functions.

Comment: Yes you can... though I forgot to give the temp table an alias.